# About ord.als library

Tags: alloy

How can I use the ord.als library in Alloy 4?

I get the library from here: http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/user/golem/papers/898/ord.als
but I get some sintax error when I try to use it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what that `ord.als` file is, but you should instead use the ordering library (`ordering.als`) that ships with Alloy.  To access that file:

- click `File -> Open Sample Models` from main menu
- select `util/ordering.als`;

to open it in your model, simply write

```
open util/ordering[S]

sig S {}
```